# JPA: Why lock an entity before removing it?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, concurrency, locking

I have encountered some code where a read lock is set on an entity immediately before deleting it. I'm still working towards mastering the locking concepts, so maybe I'm missing something here, but I do not see any benefit to this. My understanding is that READ lock would check that the version has not changed before committing the transaction, but preventing change before an entity is removed seems pointless to me.

**Does locking an entity before removing it add any benefit / safety measure?**
Is this at all common?

The code looks like this...

Service Layer:

```
getDAO().readLock(entity);
getDAO().delete(entity);
```

DAO Layer for Lock:

```
//Code Specifies LockModeType.READ
T mergedObject = getEntityManager().merge(object);
manager.lock(mergedObject, lockMode);
//
```

DAO Layer for Delete:

```
T mergedObject = getEntityManager().merge(object);
getEntityManager().remove(mergedObject);
```

The persistence provider is hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

It ensures that entity is not changed externally between your version check and remove.

To prevent situation like this:

1. you: select (no lock)
2. external process: updates entity (as it is not locked)
3. you: delete by id - you removed an updated version with important user changes.